# Python "import as" changing global namespace

Tags: python, import, global, python-module

I'm automatically translating some perl code to python with my [pythonizer](https://github.com/snoopyjc/pythonizer) tool.  The perl code uses the Date::Manip package, which has a submodule Date::Manip::Date.  I use a `Date` variable (which I defined in `builtins`) in my generated code to hold the namespace where I define `Date.Manip`.  When I import the Date.Manip.Date package, even though I import it as `_Date_Manip_Date`, the import still sets a global `Date` variable preventing access to my `Date` namespace.  I'm looking for ideas on how to avoid this issue.  I can't change the name of the submodule.  Here is code that reproduces the problem (note I'm using `Date` as a string in this test case and not a namespace):

```
# date_issue.py:
import sys
sys.path[0:0] = '.'
import Date.Manip as _Date_Manip

# Date/Manip/__init__.py:
Date = '2023-04-15'
import Date.Manip.Date as _Date_Manip_Date
assert Date == '2023-04-15', f"Date got changed to {Date}"

# Date/Manip/Date.py (empty file)
```

I get this error on the assert:

```
AssertionError: Date got changed to <module 'Date.Manip.Date' from '/mnt/c/pythonizer/play/./Date/Manip/Date.py'>
```

I'm thinking of maybe saving the value of `Date` before the import and restoring it afterwards, and only doing this if there is a module name being imported that is the same name as any of the parent namespaces, but do you have any better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You know how if you do something like

```
import collections.abc
```

you can now write `collections.abc` and have that resolve to the right thing? That's an attribute access on the module object for the `collections` package. For that to work, the submodule has to be available as an `abc` attribute on that object.

To make that work, loading a package submodule sets that submodule as an attribute of the parent package. Because modules are only loaded the first time they're imported, this attribute assignment happens the first time a submodule is imported, no matter what that import looks like - the `as` in your import doesn't change this.

Trying to mess with this is a bad idea. All sorts of weird stuff breaks if the chain of attribute accesses `Date.Manip.Date` resolves to something other than the `Date.Manip.Date` module, the most straightforward breakage being that most ways of trying to access the submodule no longer work.

Unfortunately, you're trying to auto-translate a library written in a different language, so you don't have the option of just designing the library differently. This is just one of the many, many incompatibilities that render such auto-translation attempts mostly doomed.

---

If you're really determined to do this anyway, then saving and restoring the old value might be the way to go... except you said you defined your `Date` variable in `builtins` for some reason!?

> I use a `Date` variable (which I defined in `builtins`) in my generated code to hold the namespace where I define `Date.Manip`.

That's bizarre and introduces even more problems. The behavior I described isn't overwriting your variable. It's creating an entirely new name binding in a different namespace, that shadows your variable. You can't really "restore" the old value, because the old value is still there. You could try copying that value into `Date.Manip`'s namespace, or just deleting the `Date.Manip.Date` binding to unhide the binding in `builtins`, but both of those have their own weird issues - for example, if you try to copy the value, the variable in `builtins` and the variable in `Date.Manip` can easily go out of sync if any further assignments happen.

Comment: You're right - I can't just save and restore it as my `Date` is in builtins and this `Date` is in globals.  I'm thinking `del globals()['Date']` is what I need after the `import`.

Comment: FYI this obviously won't work in the sample code I posted in my question, but it will work in the actual generated code that has `Date` stored in builtins.  BTW, I store it there to make it global across files/modules, as that's how things work in perl.

Comment: If I have a dynamic import, where I call `            mod = __import__(module, globals=globals, fromlist=['*'])
            sys.modules[module] = mod`, will this also potentially set a global variable as well?

Comment: ^ I don't think `__import__(...)` does the same thing as `import` here as my test case now passes.  Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @snoopyjc: You must have made some other change inadvertently - the attribute-setting described in this answer will happen the first time the submodule is loaded, no matter whether the loading is triggered by `import`, a direct `__import__` call, `importlib.import_module`, or some other call. (Also, you don't need to set the `sys.modules` entry manually.)

Comment: I see why perllib.import (which implements dynamic imports) doesn't have an issue - it temporarily pushes "./A/B" to sys.path, then does the `__import__` on just A, so python doesn't know about the parent - that's why the issue does not happen with a dynamic import.  BTW, the final code I generate is like this (my test uses A::B::A):

    `import A.B.A as _A_B_A`
    `if "A.B" in sys.modules and hasattr(sys.modules["A.B"], "A"):`
        `delattr(sys.modules["A.B"], "A")`
as the other code wasn't working in all cases.